# TableView to display different images on new controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, tableview

I have finally created a `tableview` that will be populated with a certain amount of options for the user to click. Ideally, I would like the user to click a row, which will display a image on a second controller depending on the choice the user makes. For instance, **"photo1"** would display 1 picture on Controller B, while **"photo 2"** would display a different picture on Controller B. What code can I implement into my existing table view code to send to the second controller?

```
import UIKit

class adultcardiaclist: UITableViewController {

    let adultcardiac = ["photo1", "photo2", "photo3"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return adultcardiac.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "transportCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = adultcardiac[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    } 
}
```

Comment: didSelect delegate of TableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Default Delegate provided in TableView Conroller

```
 import UIKit

class CustomTableController: UITableViewController {

    let adultcardiac = ["photo1", "photo2", "photo3"]

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return adultcardiac.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "transportCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = adultcardiac[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let Vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageVC") as! imageVC

        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 0:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "screenShot")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;
        case 1:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "screenShot1")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;
        case 2:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "screenShot2")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;
        default:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "screenShot")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

**--> My imageVC Class**

```
import UIKit

class imageVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    var passedImage : UIImage! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.myImageView.image = passedImage
    }
}
```

**--> Output**

---> When TableView Controller Loaded in memory Stack

[image]

--> When a Row is Selected

[image]

--> when DidSelect Execute and displays result - New ImageVc with passed Image

[image]

**--> My StoryBoard**

[image]

Comment: Majuri ? what do you mean , Sorry !

Comment: I get an error in the imageVC class and the app crashes. it says something about the nil?

Comment: are you sure image is getting passed ? should I share a Demo Xcode project for you ? Crash is in ImageVc can be because of Either outlet is not well connected or Image you passing is not found in Bundle

Comment: Sample Project - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BXrrcbkusrAKbq2GbV0ELaYJrTq4XBAI

Comment: @IOSGEEK Thank you for that! Okay so I looked over every part of your files compared to mine and im almost  positive they are the same (99%). When I click on a row to display the image, the new controller opens with a blank white page. I have placed my images in the assets folder and made sure they are named correctly. I have also held control and dragged the outlet into the imageVC file. Any reason that you can think that I could be receiving this problem? I've looked over everything this weekend and just can't figure it out! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12lXzkmgI0L2MT0DvoAANE_AAQSkgmkbM . Not sure if thats the correct way to share the project, but let me know if its not. But would you be willing to just take a look at it and see what mistake im making in my project? I've been looking over it and over it and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, and when i make a change, it screws something else up... starting to irritate me haha. I''m sure its something simple that i'm over looking but I can not for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: I dont have permission to access file at link make it public, please in sharing setting of file in drive, I had requested for access please let me know when you gave permission I will check

Comment: just gave you access. thank you! I should let you know that when you run the app, the way to access the table view is to click on "Protocols" and then "Adult" and that will take you to the tableview. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: not able to Build the app Error **Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1**

Comment: if you want to share project on drive , First compress the Project folder that contains all files and then upload zipped file on drive

Comment: Just sent the email. also sent a link to chat to make easier for you

Comment: **(null): Did not find storyboard named "EKG1" referenced from Tools.storyboard** Any idea ?

Comment: Weird,I don't get that error whenever I build or run. But if you just go into the Tools Story board, you can delete the EKG1 activity reference, and any others that pop up.

Comment: I did , I made a EKG1 storyboard just to make it run, i am going to share the working one in mail

Comment: Thank you. Mind sharing what changes you made to make it work since I have to make many more tableviews?

Comment: Please check email and look for new link There and if it works Kindly accept my answer and close the thread, if any query just comment , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your didSelectRowAt indexPath, add the following line

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
```

You should declare the imageUrl variable in your second viewcontroller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "segue" {

                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                    let selectedRow = indexPath.row
                    let passingVal = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
                    passingVal.imageUrl = self.imageUrlArr[selectedRow] as? String
                }
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Your  `didSelectRowAt` pass the selected index image to next viewController**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt
 indexPath: IndexPath){
    let controller = YourSecondVC(nibName:"YourSecondVC",bundle:nil)
    controller.selectedImageName = self.adultcardiac[indexPath.row]
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

}
```

**In Your second ViewController create an variable to receive first screen image name**

```
var selectedImageName:String = ""
```

**In your secondViewController's viewWillAppear
load image into imageView**

```
self.YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.image = UIImage(named:"\(selectedImageName:String)")
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I don't see the 'didSelectRowAt' in my file. Would it be possible for you to edit my code to show me where It needs to go?

Comment: Also I get an unidentified error when typing the second controller name in "YourSecondVC" spot

Comment: didSelectRowAt one of the delegate method of UITableView to identify selected index position of tableView. If you use xib based ViewController use `let controller = YOURSECONDVC(nibName:"YOURSECONDVC",bundle:nil)` or if you use storyboard based view controllers which is connected by segue use `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"YOURSEGUE",sender:nil)` and in your `prepareForSegue` check segue.identifier and pass data to nextView Controller

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have segue between your first and second view controllers (From the table view controller one to the Detail view screen). Make sure that the segue has a name.for e.g. "imageScreen"

Now in your first view controller's didSelectRowAtIndexPath event, Invoke the segue like this.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("imageScreen", sender: nil)
```

Now in the prepareForSegue method of the first view controller, you can customize it to send more details.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{       
   if(segue.identifier=="imageScreen")
   {
     let temp = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerB
     temp.imageName = "Photo"
   }
}
```

Assuming Your Detail screen's class is called ViewControllerB and it has a property called imageName of String type. You may update the code to use your real view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use `didSelect` Delegate Method Like this

if creted from code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedImage = adultcardiac[indexPath.row]
       let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
       secondViewController.image = selectedImage
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

if creted from storyBoard

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedImage = adultcardiac[indexPath.row]
       let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController
       secondViewController.image = selectedImage
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```