# How to show different photos from an array in the detail view (coming from a collection view)

Tags: image, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, swift4

After researching and trying loads of varieties of code, I finally found a post here on Stack Exchange ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678032/tableview-to-display-different-images-on-new-controller)) that seemed to help me reach **my goal** which is: 
**Having a UICollectionView with 24 items (cell with label and image) and when the user taps on an item, a specific image is to be shown on a detail view** (> Detail view = UIViewController presented modally with a segue. No embedded NavigationController at this point, as I don't want a NavBar).

I adapted the solution from the above link to my situation (of course not sure if I did that right). I don't get any code related errors. The UICollectionView loads, I can tap on an item and the detail view opens, but the images are not shown on the detail screen. When I set a breakpoint at *override function... didSelectItemAt* I realised the code is not even called.

I've been trying for two days now to get to work. I tried various alternative options as well, but as I am total beginner in Swift as well as development in general, I just can't figure it out.

What did I miss?

**Here's my ViewController Code**
(Yes, there is probably a nicer way to load the doorImage  array, but it works, so that's fine)

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

let doorTitle = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"]

let doorImage = [UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "xmasballcut"),
                 UIImage(named: "reddecocut"),]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.collectionView.delegate = self
   self.collectionView.dataSource = self
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return doorTitle.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCellDoor", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellDoor
    cell.doorTitleLabel.text = doorTitle[indexPath.item]
    cell.doorImageView.image = doorImage[indexPath.item]
    return cell
 }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
    switch indexPath.item
    {
    case 0:
        vc.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "detail1")!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueOpenDetail", sender: self)
        break;
    case 1:
        vc.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "detail2")!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueOpenDetail", sender: self)
        break;
    case 2:
        vc.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "detail3")!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueOpenDetail", sender: self)
        break;
    default:
        vc.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "detail1")!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueOpenDetail", sender: self)
        break;
    } }
}
```

**Here's my DetailViewController Code**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var closeButton: UIButton!

var selectedImage: UIImage! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.detailImage.image = selectedImage
}


@IBAction func dismissModalView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I discussed my issue with a friend and he found the following issues:

1.) I had put a button on the CollectionView item which basically lead the whole code to another direction and thus the method was never called. This is not visible here. So I removed the button from the storyboard and the class.

2.) I also needed to delete the segue and also deleted the respective code lines "performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueOpenDetail", sender: self)".

Now it works! So the code I posted should work as an implementation example for everybody who wants to do a similar topic regarding detail views. Hope somebody can benefit from the input given here.